# if not in array -> array.push

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to create an array in javascript with unique elements from a JSON feed.
Maybe I think to much in php but there a simple script as below works.

```
$this = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value,$this)) {
        array_push($this,$value);
    }
}
```

In JS it doesn't:

```
var this = new Array();
$.each(data, function(i,field) {
    var value = field['needed'];
    if (!$.inArray(value, this)) {
        this.push(value);
    }
}
```

It just adds every `field['needed']` to `this`.

Full code so you know how I get my JSON

```
$(function() {
    $("#wtf").empty();
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/ahsmedia/openingsuren/api.php?first=" + cal.currentDate.format('d-m-Y'),
    function(data) {
        var camp = new Array();
        $.each(data, function(i,field) {
            var dt = field['datum'];
            var ca = field['campus'];
            var ca = ca.toLowerCase();
            if ($.inArray(ca, camp)) {
                camp.push(ca);
            }

            $("#wtf").append(field['campus'] + '  ' + cal.currentDate.format('d-m-Y') + ': ' +  " " + field['open'] + "-" + field['close'] + " " + field['type'] +  "<br />");
        });   
        console.log(camp);   
    });     
});
```

JSON looks like:

```
[
    {
        "datum": "2015-01-07",
        "type": "normal",
        "campus": "Kantienberg",
        "open": "08:00:00",
        "close": "18:00:00"
    },
    {
        "datum": "2015-01-07",
        "type": "normal",
        "campus": "Kattenberg",
        "open": "08:00:00",
        "close": "18:00:00"
    },
    {
        "datum": "2015-01-07",
        "type": "normal",
        "campus": "Mariakerke",
        "open": "08:30:00",
        "close": "18:00:00"
    },
    {
        "datum": "2015-01-07",
        "type": "normal",
        "campus": "Sint-Amandsberg",
        "open": "09:30:00",
        "close": "11:30:00"
    },
    {
        "datum": "2015-01-07",
        "type": "normal",
        "campus": "Sint-Amandsberg",
        "open": "12:00:00",
        "close": "17:30:00"
    },
    {
        "datum": "2015-01-07",
        "type": "normal",
        "campus": "Sint-Annaplein",
        "open": "08:15:00",
        "close": "12:30:00"
    },
    {
        "datum": "2015-01-07",
        "type": "normal",
        "campus": "Sint-Annaplein",
        "open": "13:30:00",
        "close": "17:30:00"
    }
]
```

I'm probably forgetting an important step before checking if the field is in the array, but I'm quite new to this, so I don't find it.

To be clear, I need an array with every unique campus like

```
['Kantienberg','Kattenberg','Mariakerke','Sint-Amandsberg','Sint-Annaplein']
```

but I get

```
["kantienberg", "kattenberg", "mariakerke", "sint-amandsberg", "sint-amandsberg", "sint-annaplein", "sint-annaplein"]
```

Comment: `this` is a reserved keyword, you should not attach variables to it

Comment: `inArray` returns `-1` if not found http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/. So it is still true. You have to check for `>-1`.

Comment: @devqon I know, I just used it in my examples. In my working code I use other, not-reserved names.

Comment: hehe, student at Ghent ?

Comment: @DOCASAREL It works! `if($.inArray(ca,camp) == -1) {camp.push(ca);}` gives me the array I need.

Comment: Nice to hear. You are welcome.

Comment: Why are you using an array, if it is really a set, what you neeed?

Comment: @meskobalazs it's a set, but I need to display everything from the set per campus. So if I have 2 times 'campus a' I don't want to show 2 lines for a, but 1 line, with the two times for a on it (so with another foreach on the new array.)

Comment: What I meant is, if you use a plain object, instead of an array, it works as a set, and you don't need to check item existence.

Comment: @meskobalazs Not quite sure what you mean or how to do it. Now I get a result like `Kantienberg 08:00:00-18:00:00
Kattenberg 08:00:00-18:00:00
Mariakerke 08:30:00-18:00:00
Sint-Amandsberg 09:30:00-11:30:00
Sint-Amandsberg 12:00:00-17:30:00
Sint-Annaplein 08:15:00-12:30:00
Sint-Annaplein 13:30:00-17:30:00` and I need `Kantienberg 08:00:00-18:00:00 
Kattenberg 08:00:00-18:00:00 
Mariakerke 08:30:00-18:00:00 
Sint-Amandsberg 09:30:00-11:30:00 12:00:00-17:30:00 
Sint-Annaplein 08:15:00-12:30:00 13:30:00-17:30:00 `

Comment: In this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dr1bxwqf/1/, the open and closing times are assigned to each campus name

Comment: yes, but if a campus has 2 sets of time on 1 date, 2 lines are shown, and I need both times on 1 line, so with my new array, for each campus, I get all of the times for that campus out of my JSON and show them on 1 line.

Comment: Please check again http://jsfiddle.net/dr1bxwqf/2/, I've updated it

Comment: Oh, wow, that is indeed a much better solution. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.inArray()` returns `-1` if the value does not exist in the array. When used as a boolean, `-1` equates to `true`. You need to change your condition to explicitly check for `-1`:

```
if ($.inArray(ca, camp) == -1) {
    camp.push(ca);  
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dr1bxwqf/)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is the following:

```
var camp = {};
$.each(data, function(i, field) {
    var dt = field['datum'];
    var openClose = field['open'] + "-" + field['close'];
    var ca = field['campus'];
    if (camp[ca]) {
        camp[ca].push(openClose);
    } else {
        camp[ca] = [openClose];
    }
});
```

This yields an object which maps the campus names to the opening times, like this:

```
"name" -> ["open-close", "open-close", ...]
```

After the object is created, we just append it to the DOM:

```
for (prop in camp) {
    $("#wtf").append(prop + " ");
    for (var i = 0; i < camp[prop].length; i++) {
        $('#wtf').append(camp[prop][i]);
        if (i !== camp[prop].length - 1) {
            $('#wtf').append(" ");
        }
    }
    $('#wtf').append('<br>');
}
```

The reason why I think this method is preferable for you, is that, this way all the opening and closing times are conserved. In the other approach, only one of these intervals will remain.

The [**fiddle is located here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dr1bxwqf/3/).